# SML| foldl with if

Tags: syntax, functional-programming, sml, fold

I'm having this exercise which asks to count how many values in a boolean list are true.

I typed this:

```
fun countt xs = foldl (fn (x,y) => if x=true then y=y+1) 0 xs;
```

which, apparently, is wrong. I'm getting the following error:

```
stdIn:54.21-54.24 Error: syntax error: deleting  RPAREN INT0
```

Now, I've searched a bit and found out that RPAREN is a Syntax error. But i can't figure why there's a problem in the first place.

Comment: Is this homework? I assume that it is.

Comment: Yes, it's from Webber's Modern Programming Languages book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a functional programming language, an if expression must have both then branch and an else branch (and they must both have the same type).
Your if expression only has a then branch.

Additionally, `x=true` always evaluates to the same value as `x` so you can just write `if x then ... else ...`.

Finally, it looks like you're trying to write an assignment in the then branch.  Remember that a foldl works by repeatedly passing the accumulator (`y`) to the function as it traverses the list with `xs`.  So if you want to update the accumulator, all you have to do is return the updated value.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding both the if expression and the mess with the accumulator!! (I don't know if it's just the greek translation but webber's book isn't paticularly insightful...

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the previous answer here are the suggested modifications:

```
fun countt xs = foldl (fn (x,acc) => if x then acc+1 else acc) 0 xs;
```

The term in parenthesis is the first argument to `foldl`, the value 0 is the seed value and the `xs` is the sequence that will be folded. The function takes a value and the current element of the sequence `xs`.

The function must return a value of the same type of `0`, an integer.